# ImageView wont center in parent layout when size is set manually

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

I have a layout that has two components, a background image and an "icon" image, the icon is supposed to display an imageview at the center of the layout and the background takes up the full screen. when I set the height and width to 0dp of the icon to optimize the layout then manually set the height/width in code the image will show but in the top left of the layout. Almost like it's ignoring the center in parent attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:shadowColor="#b3000000"
        android:shadowDx="3"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="3"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

This layout is from a listview item, so later on once i've done some measurements I'll set the height/width

```
viewHolder.ivIcon.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iconWidth, iconWidth));
```

So the image shows but in the top left, I feel like I'm missing something obvious

Comment: I may be going off on a tangent here; try setting the icon as a drawableBottom for the textview. You will be able to remove the extra imageview and optimise the layout further.

Comment: Haven't thought of that, ill give it a try. Found a solution to my original question though. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whats probably happening is when you are setting the layout params you are overwriting the previous one which said center in parent. You should try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iconWidth, iconWidth);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
viewHolder.ivIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: That did it. I wasn't aware that that setting params in code overwrites the other layout params.